# The ball is thrown upwards. Will the work done by air resistence while going up be different from the work done when going down?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work, drag

Can someone help me? Will the work done by air resistence while going up be different from the work done when going down?

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Comment: Note that the velocities (and drag) going up will be greater than when coming down.

Answer (score 1):

When a ball is thrown up (as soon as it leaves the hand) work being done is mass x gravity x distance **plus** air drag force x distance.

When it reaches its highest point, and begins to fall, drag force now *opposes* gravity.

The drag force vector simply reverses its direction relative to gravity, always acting opposite the direction the ball is moving.

Comment: So, the amount of work done will be the same?

Comment: Drag is dependent on the square of velocity in any direction.